# PHP/Laravel check if given 2 values are in collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections

Database i use: Mysql

I want to loop throu a table's row's and check if two values in that row, is inside a collection(laravel).

My setup is:

I have an array that looks like this

```
[
 ['foo_id' => 1, 'bar_id' => 31],
 ['foo_id' => 1, 'bar_id' => 55],
 ['foo_id' => 2, 'bar_id' => 32],
]
```

And a database table that look like this.

```
table
+----+-----+-------+
| id | foo|   bar  |
+----+-----+-------+
| 1  |  1  |   31  |
+----+-----+-------+
| 2  |  1  |   55  |
+----+-----+-------+
| 3  |  2  |   32  |
+----+-----+-------+
| 4  |  3  |   87  |
+----+-----+-------+
| .  |  .  |   .   |
+----+-----+-------+
```

So in this example row 1,2 and 3 match my collection, but row 4 does not.

My expected output here should be that when i loop throu all rows in the table, it will return yes on the first 3, and then return false on the 4th.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use filter on Collection

```
$return = $collection->filter(function($item) use ($array) {
    foreach ($array as $entry) {
        if ($entry['foo_id'] === $item->foo && $entry['bar_id'] === $item->bar) {
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```